# JMeter - Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver ' erro in JDBC Request

Tags: testing, jdbc, jmeter, performance-testing

I have called a JDBC request and got below error in the jmeter 3.1 :--

Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver '

JDBC Configuration Settings:
refer [JDBC_Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4tug.png)

Error:--
refer [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrVkn.png)

Comment: your jtds jar should be under JMeter lib folder

Comment: @user7294900  :--  jtds-1.3.1 jar is under the Jmeter/lib folder. still getting this error

Comment: In Test Plan click Browse and add your jar file

Comment: this step is of no use..still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably didn't put the driver jar jtds-1.3.1.jar (not the zip) in jmeter/lib folder which is why you get this error.

Also ensure :

- you're not using Java 9, but Java 8

Finally , there are better drivers for Microsoft than this one:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server